# data export using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, export

I need to export data from oracle sql table into linux using shell script.

When I tried this:

`var1="$(printf "%s \n" "set pages 0 feed off" \ "select * from pi_milutin.krovni_export;"|sqlplus -s $SCHEMA/$PW@$CONN)"; \ echo "$var1" > ME_1384_DataWarehouse_$date.txt; \`

I got following:

`Data Warehouse;ME_1384;180521528;Budget for HW/SVC;25/07/2022;10;9999;Krovni ugo vor;25/07/2022;24;;1;;10;30;656;20;10;30;53;25/07/2022;24;27,25;27,25;EUR;;;01/0 7/2022`

What do I have to do to get the same result on a line instead of 2 lines????

Comment: I don't understand where you have 2 lines. You did not show where line breaks show up. However you can use `tr` to remeove newline characters.

Comment: The output supposed to look like one line but breaked it 2 lines, on this specific place:"Krovni ugo", it supposed to look like "Krovni ugovor" and the rest of line.

Comment: Well, anyway, so just remove the newlines then, as I suggested in my comment.

Comment: @user1934428 I tried this:
` var1="$(printf tr -d "%s \n" "set pages 0 feed off" \
  "select * from pi_milutin.krovni_export;"|sqlplus -s $SCHEMA/$PW@$CONN)"; \
  echo "$var1" > ME_1384_DataWarehouse_$date.txt; \`

and it didn't work out. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong by writing this code?
I am new at linux, that's the key problem.

Comment: The `tr` does not make sense after the printf. The first argument of printf si the format string and the `tr` is pointless. To remove a newline, you pipe of course the output of SQL into `tr`. Don't forget to read the man-page for tr to understand its use.

Comment: @user1934428 been trying different things, didn't work out. As I already said, I am new at linux, that's why I've been having a problem with this issue. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: We can comment only to code you have posted. Publish the _different things_ you are refering here in your question, in particular the way you tried to use `tr` (or `sed` or whatever you employed here). Perhaps it would even make more sense (with respect of clarity), if you ask a new question with the topic "how to remove line feeds from the standard output of a program", as this is the essential problem. Whether you are using SQL or what else, is irrelevant to this topic.